# TempVars - Get ID for use in next form

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my database the user creates a new record via a form like so;

[image]

Upon pressing the save button, the record then gets inserted into **ConTblConsumables**, Here is the code sample behind the save button;

```
    Private Sub btnSave_Click()

    Dim strAddNewConsumable As String
    Dim strCompany As String
    Dim strConName As String
    Dim strConID As String
    Dim strCboConSupplier As String
    Dim strConTargetLevel As String
    Dim strConCost As String

        strCompany = Me.ConCompany
        strConName = Me.txtConName
        strConID = Me.txtConID
        strCboConSupplier = Me.CboConSupplier
        strConTargetLevel = Me.txtConTargetLevel
        strConCost = Me.txtConCost

        strAddNewConsumable = "INSERT INTO ConTblConsumables(strConCost, ConName, ConExtraID, Supplier, ConTargetLevel, Cost)" _
                    & "VALUES('" & strCompany & "', '" & strConName & "', '" & strConID & "', '" & strCboConSupplier & "', '" & strConTargetLevel & "', '" & strConCost & "')"

        CurrentDb.Execute (strAddNewConsumable)

        MsgBox "Record Inserted", vbExclamation

End Sub
```

[image]

Once the record has been inserted I then wish to pop-up another form where the user can then assign a parent machine to this part. The reason I wish to do it this way is that several machines can use the same part (Many-to-Many). Which when the machine is selected will then update this table;

[image]

The consumable column is a ComboBox with a relationship to the **ConTblConsumables** table and thus why I require to have the ID from previous to be retained in a TempVar.

I believe that if I was to use TempVars towards the end of the code on the save button, that when the record is inserted into the table **ConTblConsumables**, that the TempVars records the ID of the row that the record has been inserted into, thus being about to attain the ID for use in the next form.

My question is how do I write this in code? Or even if this is possible?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: It's possible. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50016139/7296893) for an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, in table `ConTblConsumables` you have a key column `ID` with `Autonumber` data type and you need to know ID of inserted row. If so, you'd better to use recordset instead of INSERT statement. Something like this:

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from ConTblConsumables")

With rst
    .AddNew
    'here ID already known and you can store it in your variable
    TempVars!MyID = !ID.Value
    !strConCost = Me.ConCompany
    !ConName = Me.txtConName
    ....
    .Update
End With

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
```

Comment: This seems to be the right way but I am getting an error message of; Run-time error '32538': TempVars can only store data. They cannot store objects. I dont have much experience with Record sets nore TempVars so please bare with me :D I have attached a picture at the bottom of my main post so you can see that it is indeed recording the last value but i think the format might be off?

Comment: Use `!ConID.Value` instead

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this. Also seems a much easier way to insert a new record in comparison to what I currently have. Thank you again!