# Lockups in MultiUser (Inserting Dummy Entries to Add New Item) in MS Access 2016

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

In a database I administer, to create a new Stock Item, it adds a dummy entry and then opens this new entry in the usual Form for editing. See the code below.

The code works until you have the database open on more than one PC.

If the user on the first PC adds a new item, due to the dummy entry there is a 10-20 second delay on everything they do on the second PC.

I'm trying to think of a simple / elegant way to achieve this without using a dummy entry (because it doesn't actually have a StockCode until the user enters one, I think on the second PC the program chokes on the dummy entry with no StockCode).

```vb
Case vbKeyF1                                                                            
' F1 Key to Add New Record      
stokmastSQL = "INSERT INTO tblSTOKMAST (STOCKCODE, PER, SELL1, SELL2, SELL3, GST) VALUES ('', '', 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 'N');"

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False                                                             ' Turn off SQL warnings for Action Queries
        DoCmd.RunSQL stokmastSQL
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True                                                              ' Re-enable SQL warnings for Action Queries        
    [Forms]![frmSTOKMASTLIST]![lst_STOKMASTLIST].Requery                                ' Requery ListBox after change
    SQL = "SELECT STOCKCODE, DESCR, PER, SELL1  FROM tblSTOKMAST ORDER BY STOCKCODE"            ' Re-initialize Record Source of ListBox
    [Forms]![frmSTOKMASTLIST]![lst_STOKMASTLIST].RowSource = SQL
   
    [Forms]![frmSTOKMASTLIST]!lst_STOKMASTLIST.SetFocus                                 ' Set Focus to ListBox and select first record
    [Forms]![frmSTOKMASTLIST]!lst_STOKMASTLIST.Selected(0) = True
    
    ' Open new record in frmSTOKMASTEDIT
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmSTOKMASTEDIT", , , "[STOCKCODE] = '" & [Forms]![frmSTOKMASTLIST]![lst_STOKMASTLIST].Column(0) & "'"

    KeyCode = 0
End Select
```

Comment: Add the _UserId_ to the table. Then, when opening the dummy record, filter on _UserId_.

Comment: Is this a split db? Why do you feel need for 'dummy' (blank) entry to begin with? Open form to new record row and user enters data.

Comment: You are opening form to blank record - where STOCKCODE is empty string? Multiple users means there could be multiple blank records. Is there an autonumber ID field? Use `CurrentDb.Execute` instead of `DoCmd.RunSQL` and code can pull new ID to use in filter criteria. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50016139/access-sql-get-the-identity-value-of-the-affected-record-from-an-insert-stateme

Comment: If it is not a record without a STOCKCODE and adding a UserID is out, you could avoid using tblSTOCKMAST in favor of a similar local table or even local variables.  Then insert the record into tblSTOCKMAST after the STOCKCODE is added and the record is saved

Comment: "Is this a split db? Why do you feel need for 'dummy' (blank) entry to begin with? Open form to new record row and user enters data."   How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a MASSIVE HUGE LARGE difference here between a long delay, and that of something not working.

What you described so far is something that is SLOW, not that it does not work.

About once a week on SO, this issue comes up, and has come up for about the last 20 years in a row!!!

You don't want to try and write a boatload of code to fix this issue, since virtually EVERYTHING you do will have to be fixed, and in 99% of cases, writing code will NOT fix this issue!!!

In other words, this is NOT due to the dummy entry, but something wrong.

You don't mention/note if the database is split - but lets leave that issue for a bit.

The first test/thing to try?

Do this:

launch the applcation. Now, open ANY table (and you not noted if you using linked tables here - a MASSIVE issue we need to know here).

Now, from the nav pane, open ANY table. Now minimize the table (assuming the application is in windowed mode. But, regardless, JUST OPEN any table.

At this point, now launch the form that creates the new record. is it slow?

The above is what we call a persistent connection. By opening a table (any table), then this forces access to keep the database open. And in multi-user mode, this "opining" process can be VERY slow (like 20 seconds).

So, first and foremost, try the above. So, you can open ANY table (and if using linked tables, then ANY linked table). Now, just leave that table open, and now again try your form. The delay (even with 2 users) should not be gone.

if you don't address this delay, then that dealy will start to appear everywhere, and will appear even without writing code.

And conversly, then writing code will not fix this issue.

If you determine the above fixes this issue? Then on application startup, you can in VBA code create what we call a persistent connection. Another way is to open a form (any form) bound to a existing table.

As noted, if the above does not fix this issue, then we have to look at how that new record is added, and perhaps it uses something like dmax() or some such to get the "max ID value". In that case? Then adding a index to that column will/can fix this issue.

So, try the above first (since you can do this without any code). Just open any table, and THEN launch/use the form(s) in question, and see if the long delay goes away.