# Getting the latest date in a Session Log Query MS Access 2016

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am developing an MS Access 2016 database that will track Sales quotes, Sales orders, engineering orders, Shipping of completed orders. Multiple users will have access to different information in different information in the database.

The issue I am facing is I have a login form that gives specific access to the different groups, but the active user session that is referenced is not the latest activity but the prior session.

Any ideas on what to do to activate the current session would be appreciated.

I have a Table `tbl12SessionLog` which is populated by public function after LogIn and all subsequent activity, it is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    tbl12SessionLog.EmployeeID, tbl12SessionLog.EmployeeName, 
    MAX(tbl12SessionLog.SessionID) AS MaxOfSessionID, 
    tbl12SessionLog.SessionActivity, 
    MAX(tbl12SessionLog.TimeStamp) AS MaxOfTimeStamp,   
    tbl11Employee.Initials, qry01EmployeeAccess.PrivilegeID, 
    qry01EmployeeAccess.Privilege, qry01EmployeeAccess.FirstName
FROM 
    (tbl11Employee 
INNER JOIN 
    tbl12SessionLog ON tbl11Employee.EmployeeID = tbl12SessionLog.EmployeeID) 
INNER JOIN 
    qry01EmployeeAccess ON tbl11Employee.EmployeeID = qry01EmployeeAccess.EmployeeID
GROUP BY 
    tbl12SessionLog.EmployeeID, tbl12SessionLog.EmployeeName, 
    tbl12SessionLog.SessionActivity, tbl11Employee.Initials, 
    qry01EmployeeAccess.PrivilegeID, qry01EmployeeAccess.Privilege, 
    qry01EmployeeAccess.FirstName
HAVING 
    (((tbl12SessionLog.EmployeeID) = [TempVars]![CurrentUserID]) 
      AND ((tbl12SessionLog.SessionActivity) = "Log On"))
ORDER BY 
    MAX(tbl12SessionLog.TimeStamp) DESC;


Public Sub Session(SessionActivity As String)
 
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tbl12SessionLog (EmployeeName, SessionActivity) Values _ 
       ('" & TempVars("UserName").Value & "', '" & SessionActivity & "')"
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE qry11EmployeeExtended INNER JOIN tbl12SessionLog ON  _ 
       qry11EmployeeExtended.EmployeeName = tbl12SessionLog.EmployeeName SET _ 
       tbl12SessionLog.EmployeeID = [qry11EmployeeExtended]![EmployeeID]"

End Sub
```

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "Session"?

Comment: Do you want to pull up the record that was just created by INSERT action? Does table have autonumber key field? Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50016139/access-sql-get-the-identity-value-of-the-affected-record-from-an-insert-stateme

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` clause contains non-key columns (like `FirstName` and `Initials`) which is not how `GROUP BY` should be used because it basically _papers over_ erroneous duplicates or _cardinality-explosions_ in your queries. Additionally, you're using non-aggregate predicates in your `HAVING` clause, which means you aren't structuring your query the way SQL expects you to, which can lead to suboptimal query-plans (but as you're using MS Access... _welp_)